# Change file permissions from code behind

Tags: asp.net, file-permissions, code-behind

I wonder if its possible to change permission on file from code behind?

**PROBLEM**: Unfortunately i use AjaxFileupload to upload files to webserver. So far so good. The problem arises when the uploaded files, that are saved on a mapped folder on the webserver are to be opened. The files doesnt show up in folder (on other server), lack of permissions.

**Here is why**: AjaxFileUpload save the file in a temp folder first, then move it to actual by me defined path. The file inherit the permission from that temp folder, not the permission i have put on my mapped folder. I need to use the mapped folder and I need the permissions on the mapped folder to be inherited to the file.

**Why do i need this?** I need this because there is an desktop application that need to open the files. The mapped folder have all the correct permissions for doing this. So,  how to do? It would be easy if i can change permission on files from code behind, lets say just after i saved the file to folder, BUT is that even possible?

I read somewhere that it wasnt a good idea to change permission on the temp folder, any ideas why?

Any help would be appriciated!

edit:

[image]
[image]

So to clearify, i dont have any problems saving file to disk (server 3). My problem is that i cant see or access files on server 1, because the file doesn't inherit the mapped folder permissons. The mapped folder have permisson from both server 1 and server 3 but one the file get uploaded the file only have permission from server 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself. Basically wrote some code that gave me the name of the tempfolder on webserver where ajaxfileupload made the temp-save before moving the file to the folder i wanted it. When i had the name on that folder i basically changed permission on that folder. I only gave read and list permission on the folder because i dont want the desktop application to have any other right on the webserver. That was all i needed to get the file listed on in the mapped driver.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the problem is with the permission on the source file.  I believe the problem is the account used to run IIS does not have permission to access the mapped folder.

You can use Impersonation to grant access for the section of code that saves the file.

See these:

- [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx)
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net)
- [And this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150122/cannot-write-on-a-mapped-drive-using-impersonation)

Comment: I dont know but your answer seems to fix issue with uploading file, thats not my problem. OR don't I understand anything? Look at my edit for better explanation about problem.